# Different regex behaviour in web page and Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying out this regex on this page:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

where Regex=`(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook\.com\/([\w\-\.]*)?`

and Subject String = `http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx`

This returns me two matches: `http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx` and `xxxxxx`

The same javascript I have embedded in my chrome extension, however there it shows me only one match: 'http://www.facebook.com/' . Any ideas ? Following is the code:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook\.com\/(?:profile\.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?");
  var m = re.exec("http://www.facebook.com/xxxxx");
  if (m == null) {
    alert("No match");
  } else {
    var s = "Match at position " + m.index + ":\n";
    for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      s = s + m[i] + "\n";
    }
    alert(s);
  }
```

Comment: In your first example, there aren't really two matches - the first entry is the part of the string that matches the pattern. The second entry is the part within the capturing group.

Comment: @George : Sorry, but i do not understand. The same is running on that web page and chrome extension. Still the output is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When regexp comes from a string, each backslash should be masked:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:http:\\/\\/)?(?:www.)?facebook\\.com\\/(?:profile\\.php\\?id=(?=\\d.*))?([\\w\\-]*)?");
```

In javascript you can also create regexp patterns without strings:

```
var re = /(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook\.com\/(?:profile\.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?/;
```

Comment: +1. I was surprised it didn't throw an exception, but the only thing it seems to have a problem with is the `\w` in `[\w\-]`.  Since that part of the regex is optional anyway, the match succeeds without consuming the `xxxxx` part.